# Theano/numpy advanced indexing

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision, theano

I have a 4d theano tensor (with the shape (1, 700, 16, 95000) for example) and a 4d 'mask' tensor with the shape (1, 700, 16, 1024) such that every element in the mask is an index that I need from the original tensor. How can I use my mask to index my tensor? Things like sample[mask] or sample[:, :, :, mask] don't really seem to work.

I also tried using a binary mask but since the tensor is rather large I get a 'device out of memory' exception.

Other ideas on how to get my indices from the tensor would also be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does `mask` contain 1D indices or 4D indices? I mean, `i = mask[0,0,0,0]` is a an integer `i < 1 * 700 * 16 * 95000` or just indexes the last dimension `[0,0,0,i]`?

Comment: Just indices for the last dimension. So every element in the 4th dimension of the mask is an index that I want from the 4th dimension of the tensor. I could create the mask differently though if it makes the problem simpler. (the mask is created with numpy, outside the computational graph, on the cpu => complete freedom)

Answer (score 0):

So in the lack of an answer, I've decided to use the more computationally intensive solution which is unfolding both my data the the indices tensors, adding an offset to the indices to bring them to global positions, indexing the data and reshaping it back to original.

I'm adding here my test code, including a (commented-out) solution for matrices.

```
def theano_convertion(els, inds, offsets):
  els = T.flatten(els)
  inds = T.flatten(inds) + offsets
  return T.reshape(els[inds], (2, 3, 16, 5))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # command: np.transpose(t[range(2), indices])
  # t = np.random.randint(0, 10, (2, 20))
  # indices = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 2))

  t = np.random.randint(0, 10, (2, 3, 16, 20)).astype('int32')
  indices = np.random.randint(0, 10, (2, 3, 16, 5)).astype('int32')
  offsets = np.asarray(range(1, 2 * 3 * 16 + 1), dtype='int32')
  offsets = (offsets * 20) - 20
  offsets = np.repeat(offsets, 5)

  offsets_tens = T.ivector('offsets')
  inds_tens = T.itensor4('inds')
  t_tens = T.itensor4('t')

  func = theano.function(
    [t_tens, inds_tens, offsets_tens],
    [theano_convertion(t_tens, inds_tens, offsets_tens)]
  )

  shaped_elements = []
  flattened_elements = []

  [tmp] = func(t, indices, offsets)

  for i in range(2):
    for j in range(3):
      for k in range(16):
          shaped_elements.append(t[i, j, k, indices[i, j, k, :]])
          flattened_elements.append(tmp[i, j, k, :])

          print shaped_elements[-1] == flattened_elements[-1]
```